# Argparse with argcomplete - Unrecognised arguments?

Tags: python, bash, autocomplete, argparse, tab-completion

I'm not quite clear on how to use argparse and argcomplete. I'm trying to write a completion script that uses Bash to call a Python script, which uses argparse/argcomplete.

The Bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

_comp_func() {
    local cmds=${COMP_WORDS[@]}
    COMPREPLY=()
    COMPREPLY=`python argcomp.py $cmds`
}
```

The Python script `argcomp.py`:

```
!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from os import environ as ENV
sys.path += ["...path to argcomplete module"]

import argcomplete, argparse

def TestCompleter(**kwargs):
    return "foo bar baz"

def main():        
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='argc')
    parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    completer = TestCompleter
    completer(parser=parser)

    argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The idea being that when I type `argc` and hit , I can generate a list of completions using argcomplete.

If I type `argc <TAB>`, then it returns:

```
usage: argc [-h] [--foo]
argc: error: unrecognized arguments: argc
```

If I type `argc --foo<TAB>`, then it returns the same thing.

If I type `argc foo`, or anything else, it will return:

```
usage: argc [-h] [--foo]
argc: error: unrecognized arguments: argc foo
```

So it doesn't recognise the name of the program as an argument itself. I thought that was handled by `argparse.ArgumentParser()` itself, but when that didn't work I tried adding `argc` as the program for the `ArgumentParser()` method. That didn't work either.

I even tried changing the command from `argc` to `baz`, just in case it was a reserved word issue. As far as I can tell it isn't. Can anyone guide me on what I'm doing wrong here, and how to get this simple example working?

Comment: The name of the script is the first element `sys.argv`.  This `sys.argv[0]` is used by `argparse` as the `prog` parameter in the `usage` display.  It is not an 'argument'.  The  parsing is done on `sys.argv[1:]`.

Comment: Ah okay. Even when I omitted that argument, it was still coming up with the same problem though. Any idea how to get it to recognise 'argc' or whatever I choose as the command name as an argument?